# Use emacs to edit C files with pico style

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'd like emacs to indent my C sources using [pico editing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Pico_style).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local c-basic-offset 2))
```

That will give you code like this:

```
int foo()
{ int x = 5;
  int y = bar(x);
  return x + y; }
```

Comment: I added that to `.emacs` but when I hit TAB after the `{` nothing happens, nor when I hit TAB after the `return` statement... I was hoping to have 2 spaces inserted. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `TAB` will increase or decrease the indentation of the current line to make the indentation correct. It will only add or remove spaces from the beginning of the line. So I don't think it can work the way you want without writing some extra code.

Comment: OK, thanks for your posts Brian (I hope saying thanks is allowed).